# Представляет для меня интерес

Tags: стилистика

Почему мы говорим "Азербайджанская Республика", но "Республика Армения"? В чем разница? И там, и там речь о названиях государств.

Comment: А что, нельзя разве говорить "Республика Азербайджан"? Это противоречит каким-либо нормам (языка, этикета...)? Уточните ситуацию: кто это - "мы говорим". **Я** говорю обычно просто "Армения", "Азербайджан".

Comment: Речь идёт о об официальном названии

Comment: Тогда так и пишите: не "почему мы говорим", а почему "Правительство РФ официально называет"...

Comment: Почему это "Правительство РФ официально называет"?.. В первую очередь государство само себя называет определенным образом. К примеру, бывшая УССР теперь официально именует себя "Украина", и никак иначе,Канада - тоже просто "Канада",Бельгия - "Королевство Бельгия",Италия - "Итальянская Республика", Израиль - "Государство Израиль",У России два раноправных официальных именования "Россия" или "Российская Федерация",Германия - "Федеративная Республика Германия"(Bundesrepublik Deutcshland) и так далее,все есть в интернете.А в обиходной,неофициальной речи можно употреблять привычное-Америка,Куба.

Answer (score 1):

Русский язык дает две возможные формы для названия государства, а выбор делается с учетом исторических факторов.

И по поводу грамматики. Республика Армения - это приложение перед именем собственным, согласование в падеже.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
При образовании названия "Республика Армения", возможно, использована традиция уже существующих исторических названий (еще до нашей эры существовали какое-то время государства Великая Армения, Малая Армения). На название "Азербайджанская Республика" повлияли какие-то другие факторы, об этом должны судить профессиональные историки.

Comment: Я не соглашаюсь с вами в том вопросе, что, по вашим  словам, армяне древний, устоявший народ, азербайджанцы сформировались в более познее время,  поэтому названия их государств получили такую форму. Ссылаетесь на историю.  А как объяснить  различие по форме образования между названиями государств Федеративная Республика Германия и Российская Федерация. Во вашему выходит, что Германия устоявшее, а Россия неустоявшее государство. Во-первых, ваш вопрос провакационный. Армяне переселены на Кавказ

Comment: из территорий Сирии и Турции.Во-вторых, да, эта война ожесточила обе стороны, много воды должно утечь,чтоб опять начать жить мирно.Но это сделать просто необходимо! И чем быстрее-тем лучше. Мы-соседи! И никуда от этого не денемся. А,как гласит пословица,"близкий сосед лучше дальнего родственника".Это нужно сделать ради наших детей.Не оставлять им в наследство злобу и вражду!

Comment: Я вижу, что мне следовало ограничиться при ответе одним предложением по поводу грамматики, но мне хотелось показать это на фактах, которые взяты из ВИКИПЕДИИ. Я не историк, поэтому могу пользоваться только общей информацией. К сожалению, Вы меня НЕ ПОНЯЛИ. И я повторяю еще раз: на выбор названия влияют РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ ИСТОРИЧЕСКИЕ ФАКТОРЫ, в каждом случае это длинная история. На нашем сайте политика не обсуждается, поэтому я корректирую ответ, заменяя его более кратким сообщением.

Answer (score 1):

Все же оформлю в виде ответа.

В первую очередь государство само себя называет определенным образом, а на русский язык это название просто переводится, и никакого выбора нет. К примеру, бывшая УССР теперь официально именует себя "Украина", и никак иначе,Канада - тоже просто "Канада",Бельгия - "Королевство Бельгия",Италия - "Итальянская Республика", Израиль - "Государство Израиль",у России два раноправных официальных именования - "Россия" или "Российская Федерация",Германия - "Федеративная Республика Германия"(Bundesrepublik Deutcshland) и так далее,все есть в интернете.А в обиходной,неофициальной речи мы, конечно, можем употреблять привычное - Америка, Куба, Франция(вместо "Французская Республика"), даже неправильное Англия(вместо "Соединенное Королевство Великобритании и Северной ...).

Answer (score 1):

Oktay, если если вас интересует не конкретная история двух республик и их взаимоотношений, а правила использования подобных названий в русском, то никаких особенных смысловых или стилистических особенностей в тот или иной вариант из этих двух не вкладывается.

Иногда выбор варианта объясняется стремлением приблизить название к тому, как оно звучит на языке "оригинала", иногда - стремлением избежать смешения с историческими государствами со сходными названиями или наоборот подчеркнуть преемственность - но это все не носит обязательного характера. Возможно отступление, например,просто по фонетическим мотивам...

Не хотелось бы искать тут какую-то политическую составляющую.

Answer (score 0):

В этой же википедии (она есть и свободная энциклопедия), на которую вы ссылаетесь, есть высказывания Василия Львовича Величко (1860-1903) и А. С. Пушкина против армян. Ваше толкование моего вопроса имеет и подстрочный смысл. "Велика Армения", "Малая Армения..." Это шовинистический бред, вымысел такой же, какой выдвигал Гитлер в своё время , чем он кончился всем известно(Великая Германия).Вы употребляете слово "возможно". Это вводное слово означает "вероятно", но не точно. Я не получил профессионального ответа на поставленный вопрос. Вы уклонились от ответа. Это же умаляет имидж сайта. Этот сайт создан для благих намерений , а не средством пропаганды и злоупотребления. У каждого народа есть национальное достоинство и чувство. К ним я отношусь с уважением.

Comment: Зачем вы **здесь** пишете, что где-то есть высказывание против кого-то (при этом высказывание, никак не связанное с языкознанием)? Это не политический форум.

Comment: Надо пересмотреть, там найдёте

Comment: Нет, я не буду "там" смотреть. Мы здесь и сейчас. Если вы __здесь__ не покажете связь ваших высказываний с языкознанием, к вам придёт злой Модератор. Выключите радио! Он уже едет по вашей улице!

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях, как правило, зависело от желания правительства страны в начале 1990-х, когда устанавливались эти названия. Армяне захотели быть Республикой Армения, а азербайджанцы Азербайджанской республикой.  Второй вариант менее распространён в российской дипломатии, но тоже применяется: *Французская Республика, ГДР, ЦАР, ЮАР* и др.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но  с небольшим замечанием: слово "Республика" в названии страны пишется с прописной буквы.

Comment: "В 1918 году были провозглашены две республики (в разных вариантах:Азербайджанская Демократическая республика и Республика Армения. Далее республики числились в составе СССР, а в 1991 году вернули себе прежние названия". Эту информацию, взятую из Интернета, я приводила в своем ответе - теперь хотелось бы, чтобы ее подтвердил историк.

Comment: @София, как историк я факт образования таких государств подтверждаю, официальные названия не знаю, не моя специализация, но в этих вопросах Википедия врёт редко.